# Spread Operation and Typescript Phenomenon

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am quite new to typescript, can someone please explain why typescript can't detect the following error? A method's parameter accepts an object with **3** properties but there was no typescript error when an object with **4** properties was passed in.

```
 const consoleLog = (params: { a: number; b: number; c: number }): void => {
    console.log(params);
  };
  const test = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
  };
  consoleLog({ ...test });
```

Thank you.

Comment: "Liskov Substitution Principle" -  a superclass shall be replaceable with objects of its subclasses without breaking the application. Type of `test` extends from type of `params`, then `test` can replace for `params`

Comment: "Structural typing vs Nominal Typing". Typescript uses structural: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/typescript/language/structural-typing.ts

Comment: @ippi I don't think this is a nominal vs structural question, it seems like an exact type vs subtype question.

Comment: Then I learned something today. I'll read up on it. Thanks

Comment: @ippi TypeScript doesn't have a notion of exact types but sometimes people expect such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

No error is thrown, because the object you're passing in is compatible with the one the function expects.

`(params: { a: number; b: number; c: number })` means that the object needs to have an `a` property, a `b` property, and a `c` property, with each of them being numbers. It doesn't mean that those are the *only* properties the object can have; it's fine to pass in an object with additional properties.

For more information on type compatibility, [see this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out) (emphasis added in the following quote):

> The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that x is compatible with y if y has **at least** the same members as x.

Comment: This is absolutely true but I think he may be confused because it is an error in a fresh object literal the difference _appears_ subtle. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&target=99&ts=4.0.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBKkgDYFMAyIDmMC8MAUADgIYBORAthAFwwDeMRNYAruQEbIkDcMbTrHbnH7tOMAL4BKGgDcQASwAmOAHx0AsACgYO+BCTIAdIkyFSFCJK5bx1zXthRk0HBu07GMAIwAaLTt4aACY-d2EYAGZQgMUaABZQ2y09A3QMPHpDLKcXKTtk8H0UNIz-DxpfMsCYEKrgGiiq2JgEmysgA)

Comment: Thank you, but how does it explain that passing the object directly in the parameter would throw and error?

consoleLog({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
  });

Comment: It’s a concept called "freshness" of object literal, documented on offical ts site. Try search for it. Basically when you pass in object literal directly, ts will check and save you from typos.

Comment: Thank you. Very interesting. https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/freshness